# A tool to monitor change in a memory address

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory

I'm debugging a multi-threaded C++ application that fails in release mode, but not in debug mode. Is there a tool that can help with monitoring a memory change at certain address and show thread that performed the change?

Comment: If you run a debug-build *outside* the debugger (like you would run a release build), does it work as well? Have you tried changing optimization levels or flags? Have you tried building the release with debug information and run in (and outside of) the debugger?

Comment: More importantly, ***how*** does your release-build fail?

Comment: Gdb can easily watch addresses for reads/writes and break on those events, windbg too. Not that debugging release mode code is particularly fun, but it's doable.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg how would I do what you listed in VS?

Comment: @AndrewLewis: at the risk of sounding harsh, those are fairly basic competencies and can easily be found in the MSDN documentation. If you're still struggling at that level, advanced tools will only make life harder for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB can do this exact thing with a watch point. Check [this](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html) out. When you run the program in gdb, set a watch point and run the program. The program will break when a change occurs to that memory address. From there you can figure out the thread that caused it.